# How to delay in adding items in list box vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am using for, while & do while loop in vb.net to add some values in list box. I want to use a timer to delay in adding values to list box. Please tell the syntax, what should I use & Following is my code:

```
 Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click        
    Dim a As Integer
            For a = 1 To 10          
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(a)
     End If

            Next


        End Sub

        Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
            Dim b As Integer
            b = 4
            If b < 5 Then
                MessageBox.Show("eRROR")
            End If
            While b <= 3
                ListBox2.Items.Add(b)
                b = b + 1
            End While


        End Sub

        Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
            Dim c As Integer
            c = 20
            Do
                c = c + 1
                ListBox3.Items.Add(c)
            Loop While c <= 30


        End Sub

        Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

        End Sub

        Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        End Sub


    End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

A timer executes once every *n* milliseconds, you take advantage of this by handling the timer's [Tick event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer.tick?view=netframework-4.8). If you wanted to keep track of what increment you're on, either declare a private variable outside of the scope ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/scope)) of the Tick event or declare a static variable inside the Tick event.

Private Variable:

```
Private counter As Integer = 0
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    counter += 1

    If (counter < 31) Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(counter)
    Else
        Timer1.Stop()
    End If
End Sub
```

Static Variable:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Static counter As Integer = 0

    If (counter < 31) Then
        counter += 1
        ListBox1.Items.Add(counter)
    Else
        Timer1.Stop()
    End If
End Sub
```